# Can I add more "android" emoticons into my phone?

Tags: emoticons

I got all those greene faces on my phone, but can I add more of them or create my own pictures and add to my phone or not?

[image: Emoticons]

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note (N7000)

Comment: It might help if you added what phone you are using. Are you using a custom ROM? Are you rooted?

Comment: Even if you could add them, the _recipient_ would also need to have them for it to work.

Comment: I agree with Al Everett, if you want to create emoticons for just you to see then that is a different story. You should be able to select or create your own emoticons using a ROM. Even if you manage to upload your own emoticons, nobody will see them except for you.